# Python strftime German Date String

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, time, strftime

I am trying to update some of my csv files and later on my database. It seems strftime mix up day an month. I am in Germany and we write our date `DD/MM/YYYY` instead of `MM/DD/YYYY`.

How do I make a datetime object out of the germanString, it is actually already is in the format I need, but I cannot compare str to datetime object. 
If I leave out the strftime and make it simply parse(germanString) it mixes the date up totally starting with `YYYY-DD-MM`.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

lastTimeUpdated = time.ctime(os.path.getctime('myPath/myFile.csv'))
lastTimeUpdated = parse(lastTimeUpdated).strftime('%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M') 

print(lastTimeUpdated)
# 09.07.2017, 16:00

print(germanTimeString)
# 05.07.2017, 14:00   <---- is a String so far

HereIsTheProblemDate = parse(germanTimeString).strftime('%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M')

print(HereIsTheProblemDate)
# 07.05.2017, 14:00 <---- Mix up Day and Month

if HereIsTheProblemDate > lastTimeUpdate:
    doAnything() #<--- obiously doesnt arrive here
```

What do I have to do? So that the Germanstring gets converted into a datetime object without changing its values?

Comment: What is `parse`? It's not part of `datetime`.

Comment: from dateutil.parser import parse

Answer (score 2):

Rather than converting the time value returned from `getctime()` into a string, you should convert it straight into a `datatime` object. This can be done using [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromtimestamp#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

last_time_updated = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime('myfile.csv'))
print(last_time_updated.strftime('%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M'))
```

You can then compare this correctly to another `datetime` object. By avoiding a string representation, you do not have to work out how to parse the date.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for `dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) you can see that `parse` has a `dayfirst` parameter. Simply set that to `True`.